# Unable to send a json message from android app to chromecast receiver app

Tags: chromecast

Can't send a json message from my android app to the receiver app.

**Android App**

- I've created my custom MessageStream and I'm using this namespace "com.jujuy.chromecast".
- Once I get the channel from the session I attach  MyCustomMessageStream to it then and call the method to send the message.

  MyCustomMessageStream cm = new MyCustomMessageStream();
  channel.attachMessageStream(cm);

  cm.sendTestMessage("Hello!");

**Receiver App**

```
var receiver = new cast.receiver.Receiver(
    APP-ID, 
    ["com.jujuy.chromecast"],
    "",
    5);

var channelHandler =  new cast.receiver.ChannelHandler("com.jujuy.chromecast"); // I think it's not necessary to use com.jujuy.chromecast

channelHandler.addEventListener(cast.receiver.Channel.EventType.MESSAGE, onMessage.bind(this));

channelHandler.addChannelFactory(receiver.createChannelFactory("com.jujuy.chromecast")); 

receiver.start();

// message listener
function onMessage(event) {
    document.getElementById("messageLabel").innerHTML = event.message.type;
}
```

After start the session () I receive this message 
"failed to start application: no channel info received"
on onSessionStartFailed() method and the tv screen turns black.

I think something is wrong with the world "com.jujuy.chromecast", I saw in other examples they use cast.receiver.RemoteMedia.NAMESPACE, I'm not sure if I can change it with the namespace used in MyCustomMessageStream.

I saw in TicTacToe example they use a different way to get de CastDevice object than the documentation says. Could be this the problem?

My chromecast is whitelisted and I was able to run many examples without problem.

I used a custom receiver app  to test play video and audio. Any idea?

Comment: In the constructor for your `MyCustomMessageStream` class, did you call `super("com.jujuy.chromecast");` to set the namespace for the super `MessageStream` class?

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because your namespace on the sender doesn't match the namespace on the receiver. You need to make sure you pass it in as a parameter to the constructor for your custom MessageStream.

Here's an example:

```
public class MyCustomMessageStream extends MessageStream {

    private static final String APP_NAMESPACE = "com.jujuy.chromecast";

    protected MyCustomMessageStream(){
        super(APP_NAMESPACE);
    }

    public final void sendTestMessage(String message){
        // ...
    }

    //...

}
```

You shouldn't need to use the remote media namespace to send messages, that's for media playback. Here's a more in depth answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/18499253/1839298

At first I couldn't get my package namespace to work, you might try a single word namespace, like 'TEST', to see if you can get that working then proceed from there.